# Error deploying angular-cli project to github pages

Tags: angular-cli

I am getting the following error on my first try deploying my first angular-cli app to github pages. How do I fix this?

"You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the github-pages:deploy command."

```
[18:07:12] (gh-pages) ang-cli
// ♥ ls -l
total 1480
drwxr-xr-x+  7 Dan  staff     238 May 13 17:11 app
drwxr-xr-x+ 10 Dan  staff     340 May 13 17:11 dist
-rw-r--r--+  1 Dan  staff    5430 May 13 17:11 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--+  1 Dan  staff    1102 May 13 17:11 index.html
-rw-r--r--+  1 Dan  staff  735813 May 13 17:11 main.js
drwxr-xr-x+ 93 Dan  staff    3162 May 13 17:19 node_modules
-rw-r--r--+  1 Dan  staff    1572 May 13 17:11 system-config.js
drwxr-xr-x+ 43 Dan  staff    1462 May 13 17:11 tmp
-rw-r--r--+  1 Dan  staff     455 May 13 17:11 tsconfig.json
drwxr-xr-x+  6 Dan  staff     204 May 13 16:21 typings
drwxr-xr-x+  6 Dan  staff     204 May 13 17:11 vendor
[18:07:19] (gh-pages) ang-cli
// ♥ ng github-pages:deploy --message "Initial deployment"
You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the github-pages:deploy command.
[18:07:30] (gh-pages) ang-cli
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error with every ng command. I'm not sure why it's telling me I'm not in an angular-cli project.

Comment: Okay, I still don't know what caused this problem, but it's not happening in the new project I generated. Question: When the rest of you are learning a new technology, do you find yourselves having to delete the whole project and start over a lot? Or do you wait for an expert to fix a bug, then look at the diffs to see how to repair your project without deleting everything and starting over? This has been a recurring thing for me for a long time. Just curious.

Comment: sometimes I just nuke everything and start over… depends how much things I changed that I have no idea what they do

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed in this way.

```
git pull origin master
```

If you have remote project on github please you write it above. I think you have different folder structure for angular-cli.